# Julia: concatenate string and integer

Tags: julia

What is the simplest way in Julia to concatenate a string and an integer value? I would like to do something like:

```
julia> foo = "test: "
"test: "

julia> bar = 3
3

julia> foobar = foo * bar
ERROR: `*` has no method matching *(::ASCIIString, ::Int64)
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm not terribly familar with Julia, but I believe you'd be better off with string interpolation:

```
"test: $bar"
```

Or alternately:

```
string("test: ", bar)
```

Or, if you did want to use the `*` operator, I believe you'd want:

```
"test: " * string(bar)
```

Comment: Thanks, for me the last option seems to be the most useful one

Comment: I think the one with string should be the best for performance.

Comment: @DavidPSanders `string` and string interpolation are equivalent.

Answer (score 15):

You can extend the `*` generic function with a new method, using multiple dispatch to the `Union{String, Number}` type:

```python
julia> VERSION
v"0.6.0-rc1.0"

julia> *
* (generic function with 181 methods)

julia> const StrNum = Union{String, Number}
Union{Number, String}

julia> import Base: *

julia> Base.:*(x::StrNum, y::StrNum) = string(x, y)

julia> 4 * "2"
"42"

julia> "4" * 2
"42"
```

Comment: I'm new to Julia. Would you explain if/why ``println(foo, bar)`` is a bad idea? or doesn't achieve the OP's goal. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT `println` will print the stirng and return `nothing`, `string` will return the string but not print it, however the REPL always displays the last value! Returning the string is more useful than printing it, specially if you want to continue operating on it.This is just an example of how the OP could have defined his own `*` mehtod or simply use `string` instead.

Comment: I'm new to Julia. 
1.In `import Base: *`, why should there be a `:`. Is that statement akin to `from libname import utility` in python?
2. In `Base.:*`, you have used `:` again and there is an extra `.`. What  is their significance?
Thanks

Comment: @dpk `:*` is symbol for `*`. `Base.something` means something from Base.

Comment: @dpk edit: @dpk ad 1. You are right. Ad 2. `:*` is symbol for `*`. `Base.something` means something from `Base`. `Base.:*` means `:*` from `Base`. SalchiPapa wants to implement new method for `*` operator from Base. This is syntax how to achieve it. How not to use operator but "speak" about operator.